# Why are string and []bytes treated differently when unmarshaling JSON?

Tags: json, go, unmarshalling

My understanding from reading the documentation was that `string` is essentially an immutable `[]byte` and that one can easily convert between the two.

However when unmarshaling from JSON this doesn't seem to be true. Take the following example program:

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
)

type STHRaw struct {
    Hash []byte `json:"hash"`
}

type STHString struct {
    Hash string `json:"hash"`
}

func main() {
    bytes := []byte(`{"hash": "nuyHN9wx4lZL2L3Ir3dhZpmggTQEIHEZcC3DUNCtQsk="}`)

    stringHead := new(STHString)
    if err := json.Unmarshal(bytes, &stringHead); err != nil {
        return
    }

    rawHead := new(STHRaw)
    if err := json.Unmarshal(bytes, &rawHead); err != nil {
        return
    }

    fmt.Printf("String:\t\t%x\n", stringHead.Hash)
    fmt.Printf("Raw:\t\t%x\n", rawHead.Hash)
    fmt.Printf("Raw to string:\t%x\n", string(rawHead.Hash[:]))
}
```

This gives the following output:

```
String:         6e7579484e397778346c5a4c324c3349723364685a706d67675451454948455a63433344554e437451736b3d
Raw:            9eec8737dc31e2564bd8bdc8af77616699a0813404207119702dc350d0ad42c9
Raw to string:  9eec8737dc31e2564bd8bdc8af77616699a0813404207119702dc350d0ad42c9
```

Instead I would have expected to receive the same value each time.

What is the difference?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The designers of the [encoding/json](http://godoc.org/encoding/json) package made the decision that applications must provide valid UTF-8 text in `string` values and that applications can put arbitrary byte sequences in `[]byte` values.  The package base64 encodes `[]byte` values to ensure that the resulting string is valid UTF-8.

The encoding of `[]byte` values is described in the [Marshal function documentation](http://godoc.org/encoding/json#Marshal).

This decision was not dictated by the design of the Go language.  The `string` type can contain arbitrary byte sequences.  The `[]byte` type can contain valid UTF-8 text.

The designers could have used a flag in the field tag to indicate that a `string` or `[]byte` value should be encoded and which encoder to use, but that's not what they did.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I foolishly only checked the documentation for the Unmarshal function.